# protecting the URL where flash/flex app can be executed

Tags: apache-flex, flash

Is there an easy copyprotection, so that I can define in code the URL where flash/flex app can be executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a detailed tutorial on how to achieve that:

http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/quick-tip-lock-your-swf-to-a-specific-domain-name/